# How would one enable and use ES6 modules in the V8 javascript engine?

Tags: v8, es6-modules, embedded-v8

I use an embedded V8 engine in my (Windows Desktop) C++ application. I understand that V8 has support for ES6 modules. How would I go about activating and using this feature in my application?

I would not expect anyone to have a complete worked example of how this works, but a high level answer pointing me (and future readers) in the right direction would entirely fulfil my hopes and aspirations for this question.

Comment: You tried some es6 features and they're not working? How are you embedding the V8 engine?

Comment: I've not tried just enabling the features @Anas, it seems that, once enabled, there must be some configuration for me to complete before it actually works. How else would V8 know where to look on my filesystem for a file? If I use the following JS code, for example:
`import {x} from "./y.js";`
I don't think V8 would know where to look for `y.js`.

Comment: @Anas RE "how are you embedding", I think I'm embedding in a pretty standard way. Everything I do is consistent with [the "Embedder's Guide"](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Embedder%27s-Guide).

Comment: I found it very helpful (given the lack of documentation) to discover that V8's implementation for modules hews awfully close to the literal text/language of the spec. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-source-text-module-records

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In leiu of actual examples from V8 (I was actually planning to write some at some point), I will write one here. For some examples of use in the wild I recommend [Node.js's implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/module_wrap.cc), [or my own](https://github.com/devsnek/zero-archive/blob/master/src/zero_module_wrap.cc), both using very similar layouts (having been written by the same people). There is also an implementation in [D8, V8's CLI debugger](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/d8.cc?l=741&rcl=51e736ca62bd5c7bfd82488a5587fed31dbf45d5).

```cpp
Local<String> source_text = String::NewFromUtf8(
    isolate, "import 'some thing'; 1 + 1");

ScriptOrigin origin(String::NewFromUtf8("main.mjs"),      // specifier
                    Integer::New(isolate, 0),             // line offset
                    Integer::New(isolate, 0),             // column offset
                    False(isolate),                       // is cross origin
                    Local<Integer>(),                     // script id
                    Local<Value>(),                       // source map URL
                    False(isolate),                       // is opaque
                    False(isolate),                       // is WASM
                    True(isolate));                       // is ES6 module
Context::Scope context_scope(context);
ScriptCompiler::Source source(source_text, origin);
Local<Module> module;
if (!ScriptCompiler::CompileModule(isolate, &source).ToLocal(&module)) {
  // if you have a v8::TryCatch, you should check it here.
  return;
}

// You can resolve import requests ahead of time (useful for async)
for (int i = 0; i < module->GetModuleRequestsLength(); i++) {
  Local<String> specifier = module->GetModuleRequest(i); // "some thing"
}

// or you can resolve them sync in the InstantiateModule callback
module->InstantiateModule(context, [](Local<Context> context, // "main.mjs"
                                      Local<String> specifier, // "some thing"
                                      Local<Module> referrer) {
  return Local<Module>();
});

// setting this callback enables dynamic import
isolate->SetImportModuleDynamicallyCallback([](Local<Context> context,
                                               Local<ScriptOrModule> referrer,
                                               Local<String> specifier) {
  return MaybeLocal<Promise>();
});

// setting this callback enables import.meta
isolate->SetHostInitializeImportMetaObjectCallback([](Local<Context> context,
                                                      Local<Module> module,
                                                      Local<Object> meta) {
  // meta->Set(key, value); you could set import.meta.url here
});

Local<Value> result;
if (module->Evaluate(context).ToLocal(&result)) {
  String::Utf8Value utf8(isolate, result);
  printf("module eval result: %s\n", *utf8);
} else {
  // once again, if you have a v8::TryCatch, use it here.
}
```

Comment: How would you extend your example to support several modules that import from and export to each other? There would also be one main entry point module of course.

Comment: @synchronizer you'd return the requested modules from InstantiateModule.

Comment: You don't simply load an array of files at the same time, or something along those lines? Do you mean that I need to figure out the dependencies myself?

Comment: @synchronizer mapping specifiers to modules is left entirely to the host. You're responsible to decide how you resolve import requests, where the source is loaded from, etc.

Comment: @snek I'm not sure I understand why the script should be compiled as Module if the semantics should be different?

Comment: @user64204 I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @snek looking at v8 interface for module loading. It seems like any script that uses `import` is a module. I.e. it should execute once per isolate run-time. Now I'm trying to understand how the "compile once, run many times" paradigm works in a new module-based world. And it looks like, it just doesn't work at all. You cannot compile a sync function that uses a library anymore. The whole spec is unusable in an embedder's world...

Comment: @user64204 the embedder explicitly chooses whether a given source text is a script or a module. See the ScriptCompiler::CompileModule() call in my example code? if I wanted to run a script I would use ScriptCompiler::Compile() instead.

Comment: @snek yup, but `import` cannot be used in a script. Which means either everything is a module (runs a single time, suited for long running process, like server), or you need to stick with `require()`, or use `import()` which is just an ugly async-only alias to require...

Comment: Perhaps I'm blind, but could I ask for help on how to actually resolve an `import` request?  You loop over all the specifiers in the ModuleRequests, but I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do next.  How do I tell V8 that _this_ module should be linked to that specifier?